# SQL help needed combining WHERE, AND, OR

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to combine WHERE, AND, OR. But the results I'm getting aren't what I was hoping for :S
I'm trying to select the name from a table where combobox1 could be in either of the columns 2-4 and the type and region has to be Italy and Bus.

```
string SqlQry = "SELECT [Name] FROM [Table] WHERE [Column 2] = @1 OR [Column 3] = @2 OR [Column 4] = @3 AND [Region] = @4 AND [Type] = @5 ORDER BY [Name] ASC";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Combobox1.SelectedItem);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", Combobox1.SelectedItem);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", Combobox1.SelectedItem);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", "Italy");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", "Bus");
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What database is this? and what Sql classes are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add parentheses

```
WHERE 
(
  [Column 2] = @1 OR [Column 3] = @2 OR [Column 4] = @3
) 
AND [Region] = @4 
AND [Type] = @5
```

because due to operator precedence `and` binds stronger than  `or`.

You could improve this to

```
WHERE @1 in([Column 2], [Column 3], [Column 4]) 
AND [Region] = @2 
AND [Type] = @3

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Combobox1.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", "Italy");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", "Bus");
```

Comment: Yeah I did this initially, but the results are empty when I do it like that.

Comment: Then check your parameter inputs and the table content